# TCP recv() function behavior in a loop in a program?

Tags: sockets, c++11, tcp

I have a TCP connection active with socket being created with TCP_KEEPALIVE parameter.

Now,

```
While(1)
{
   int n = ::recv(socketId,buff,BUF_SIZE,MSG_WAITALL);
   if ( n > 0)
   {
     // do something
   }
}
```

Now lets say, if I don't receive data at socketId for sometime lets say 2-3 minutes ? 
what will happen ? will the program keep waiting at recv() ?

While doing this, I observed that the my program stopped after some time when I stopped receiving data on the socket : socketId.

My program did not create any core dump file, No sign of crashing or anything.
So can someone explain why the program/process stopped ?

Comment: If you have a blocking socket (the default) then yes `recv` will wait indefinitely until either there's an error, the connection is closed, or data is received.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say, as your progam is improperly written.

If `n > 0`, you received `n` bytes of data, and you can process it.

If `n == 0`, the peer has disconnected: you must close your socket and stop reading.

If `n == -1`, there was an error, and you should print it or log it, via `errno`, `strerror()`, or `perror()`, and then close the socket as above.